# Convex Optimization

Tags: convex-optimization

If $q>p>0$ show that the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$ minimizes the function  $$f(x,y) = (y-px^2)(y-qx^2)$$  locally on the lines  $$y=ht, x=kt$$ through the point (x,y).

Comment: Why is this tagged 'convex-optimization'? It doesn't look convex to me...

Answer (score 2):

Just insert the definition of $y$ and $x$ so define the function
$$g(t)=f(kt,ht)=\ldots$$
Now you have a function $g:R\rightarrow R$, where you can use standard one-dimensional analysis to show that $t=0$ is a minimal point (under certain conditions on $q$ and $p$ maybe). But this means that $f$ has a minimum in $(0,0)$ if you only consider sequences in $R^2$ that are linear (you walk on lines into $(0,0)$.

You did not ask this, but the natural question would be now: Is $(0,0)$ a minimal point of $f$.

Is this helpful?